# Svn pre-commit hook to external sources

Tags: svn, hook, svn-externals

We have huge 'global' svn repository for automatic test files. Those test are run on environment, that checkouts that repo.

Now, my team has our 'own' repository, that has only external paths to 'global' (mostly, because checkout our path takes seconds, but whole 'global'... well, 1,5h). As 'global' has no hooks, this is pretty much a trash bin repository... I wanted to avoid that by setting hooks on 'own'. However, hooks doesn't work for external resources, but only for files direct on repo. I cannot have access to 'global'.

Do you maybe know any solution or workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that hooks in svn doesn't work for external sources, they can apply only to files directly in that repository.